My X3DOM extrusion get 'twisted', can I fix this?
I am using some trig functions to generate coordinates for a 3D extrusion representation of a decorative knot.  At certain points the extrusion shape twists giving an awkward-looking appearance.  I am trying to figure out why this happens and how to stop it.
Close-up of problem in a fuller example
I have narrowed the problem down for this question to 2 minimal examples, one works, the other doesn't.  It appears to need at least 4 spine points for the problem to show up.
<html> 
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> 
    <title>X3DOM Knot</title> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.x3dom.org/release/x3dom-full.js'> </script> 
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://www.x3dom.org/download/x3dom.css'></link> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Prototype</h1>
<h2>This one looks fine</h2>
<x3d width='200px' height='200px'> 
    <scene>
        <shape>
            <appearance><material diffuseColor='0 0 1'></material></appearance> 
            <extrusion crosssection="0 0.2, 0.2 0, 0 -0.2, -0.2 0, 0 0.2"
            spine="0.06979899340500256 -1.9987816540381915 -0.6021273936415662, 0.34729635533385994 -1.9696155060244163 -0.7777777777777772, 0.6180339887498945 -1.9021130325903073 -0.9642246120749118, 0.8767422935781548 -1.797588092598334 -1.1584796584121726">
            </extrusion>
        </shape>
    </scene>
</x3d>
<h2>This one has the twist</h2>
<x3d width='200px' height='200px'> 
    <scene>
        <shape>
            <appearance><material diffuseColor='0 0 1'></material></appearance> 
            <extrusion crosssection="0 0.2, 0.2 0, 0 -0.2, -0.2 0, 0 0.2"
            spine="0.07048223458426904 -2.0183471215009843 -0.6021273936415662, 0.34729635533385994 -1.9696155060244163 -0.7777777777777772, 0.6240837360413788 -1.9207322402333793 -0.9642246120749118, 0.9102308692553865 -1.8662498479583811 -1.1584796584121726">
            </extrusion>
        </shape>
    </scene>
</x3d>
</body>
</html>

I have tried setting the orientation at each spine point to a constant value with no effect.  I do not understand why the result isn't a smooth transition from one spine point to the next in some cases yet it is in others.
